# Unique Value Index from two fields

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to pandas and python, and could definitely use some help.

I have the code below, which almost does what I want.  It creates dummy variables for the unique values in a field and indexes them by the unique combinations of the unique values in two other fields.

What I would like is only one row for each unique combination of the fields used for the index.  Right now I get multiple rows for say `'asset subs end dt' = 10/30/2008` and `'reseller csn' = 55008` if the dummy variable comes up 3 times.  I would rather have one row for the combination of index field values with a 3 in the dummy variable column.

```
Code:

df = data

df = df.set_index(['ASSET_SUBS_END_DT','RESELLER_CSN'])

Dummies=pd.get_dummies(df['EXPERTISE'])
```

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).EXPERTISE.count()
```

when you do this `groupby`, everything with the same index is grouped together. assuming your data in `EXPERTISE` is `notnull`, you will get a new `DataFrame` returned with unique index values and the `count` per each index. try it out for yourself, play around with the results, and see how it can be combined with your existing `DataFrame` to get the final result you want.

Comment: Add more context for your answer and explain the why, as your answer was up for review as a low quality answer.